# Jackson Error "no delegate- or property-based Creator" on trying to use record after upgrading to 2.15.3

Tags: java, jackson

The below code is throwing the error with Jackson 2.15.3 but the same has been working fine with 2.14.3.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class JacksonTest {

  @Test
  void test() {
    var str = """
      {"id" : "test-rest"}
    """;

    var objectMapper = new BaseObjectMapper();
    try {
      System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(str, TestResp.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Assertions.fail();
    }
  }

  record TestResp(String id) {}

  private static class BaseObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    BaseObjectMapper() {
      setVisibility(
              getSerializationConfig()
                  .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                  .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                  .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                  .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                  .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                  .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE))
          .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    }
  }
}
```

The exception I am getting with Jackson 2.15.3 is like below

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.spotnana.obt.master.apis.auth.authentication.JacksonTest$TestResp` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"  {"id" : "test-rest"}
"; line: 1, column: 4]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1915)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1360)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1424)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:352)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3772)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3740)
  at com.spotnana.obt.master.apis.auth.authentication.JacksonTest.test(JacksonTest.java:19)
```

Is this expected with Jackson 2.15.3? Can someone let me know what change in Jackson 2.15.3 lead to this?

Comment: Are those all the configurations? This works as expected for me with both `2.14.3` and `2.15.3`.

Comment: Weird. In my case it works with 2.15.3 only if I comment `withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE))`

Comment: I have uploaded the code to https://github.com/debraj-spotnana/jackson-issue/tree/main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been discussed in Jackson GitHub [channel](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/discussions/202)

There was a change in behaviour wrt to `Record` in 2.15 which has been reverted in 2.16.

Below is the relevant post

> I think that behavior for 2.16.1 is what we want, after all. The tricky question is wrt. Records' canonical constructor which is the natural choice, as records do not have default no-parameter constructors (except in rare case of no-fields records).
> So I may have misspoken earlier.

> Now that think back, I think you should be safe, and that the Canonical constructor for records is found even without auto-detection. This is partly because -- as you pointed out -- up to 2.14 it was always detected.

> We do not have plans to change this behavior in 2.16.x or later 2.x

> Apologies for confusion.